# Why is my code getting the wrong part of the txt string?

Tags: python, string, function

The issue I have is that I'm not able to get the correct part of my txt string. The txt string also has to be in the current order, I can't switch role and name.

```
   txt = \
    '''
    Company name
    leader: Claire
    cashier: Ole
    '''

    def role(name):
        start= txt.find(name)-len(name)
        end= txt.find('\n', start)
        return txt[start:end]
```

If I type role("Ole") I expect the output to be 'cashier'.
The output I am getting though is 'r: Ole'.

Comment: What do you expect `txt.find(name)-len(name)` to do? it will always be negative which will mess the indexing when you use `start`

Comment: @DeepSpace sorry, I find it a bit confusing. my intention for txt.find(name)-len(name) was that it would take the length of the name you enter in the function and start from right before the colon?

Comment: Negative indexing does not work this way. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation

Answer (score 0):

```
stringy = "cashier: Ole"
stringy.partition(':')[0]
```

you can use .partition and bring only the first element

this will work but if there is anything diff about your string it may break down.

```
stringy = """    Company name
    leader: Claire
    cashier: Ole"""
def role(name):
    slice = stringy.partition(name)[0]
    role_str = slice.split(' ')[-2]
    return role_str
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but would this work with my current function?

Comment: is the txt at the top of your question an actual .txt file?

Comment: It's just a string that I called txt, sorry if this was a bit misleading

Comment: i would probably store it as a list or dictionary instead of a string. Does it have to be a string?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary that associates the names to the correspondent roles, so that it becomes very easy to retrieve them even in a much longer list:

```
txt = \
'''
Company name
leader: Claire
cashier: Ole
'''

t = txt.split()
roles = {t[i] : t[i-1].strip(':') for i in range(3, len(t), 2)}

def role(name):
    return roles[name]
```

Once set up, it's pretty intuitive.